# Change property of a set of multiple objects with python script

Tags: python, game-engine

I am assigning a landscape's LoD models, of which there are about 100, and I need a way to change the value labeled "Distance" for all of these objects.  The naming convention for the objects I want to modify with this script is X##, where X is a letter and ## is a two-digit number.

Pretty much this (in pseudocode because I can't do Python for the life of me):

```
if name_of_object has 3 characters
   set bpy.data.objects["name_of_object"]LodLevel.distance = (some number I enter in)
```

[image]

Comment: Are you talking about Blender or about the BGE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using python string methods**

There are a number of ways to scan a string for a particular naming convention. I've used `String.isalpha()` , `String.isdigit()` to check for alphabet characters and digits.

Loop over all selected objects (Rather than all objects in file) and select all those with 3 character names, with an alpha first character, and numeric for last 2.

Warning: there is an issue with your naming convention. If there is a level of detail added to list the first level, at index 0,  will be the object itself with a distance of zero.  The script below adjusts for your current convention.

Using a list of `distances` for differing level of details.  I've matched this to the levels of detail index, ie has a zero entry for zeroth .

```
distances = [0, 3, 4, 5, 6] # XNN_LOD0 = 3
```

Ok now we have the objects, lets look at their lod levels, ignoring level 0 (itself) and any levels higher than those covered by `[distances]`. Then for each valid level set the object from the naming convention and distance.

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
# set our level distances.
distances = [0, 3, 4, 5, 6] #XNN_LOD1 = 4
# objects in file with naming conv.
obs = [o for o in context.selected_objects
        if len(o.name) == 3
        and o.name[0].isalpha() and o.name[0].isupper()
        and o.name[1:].isdigit()]

for o in obs:
    print(o.name, "levels:", len(o.lod_levels))
    for lev_index, lod in enumerate(o.lod_levels):
        if not(0 <  lev_index < len(distances)):
            continue
        # use your LOD naming convention
        name = "%s_LOD%d" % (o.name, lev_index - 1)
        lod.object = bpy.data.objects.get(name)

        print("lod[%d]" % lev_index)
        print(end = "\t")
        if lod.object:
            print("object = ", name, "distance = ", distances[lev_index])            
            lod.distance = distances[lev_index]
        else:
            # warn if no object
            print("\tCould not find:", name)
```

Notes: if you want to iterate over

- all objects in scene, replace `context.selected_objects` with
  `context.scene.objects`
- all objects in file, replace `context.selected_objects` with
  `bpy.data.objects`

in most cases I'm of the belief using the context selected objects gives more control.

Should you wish to change "_LOD0, _LOD1, ..." to "_LOD1, _LOD2" run this script

```
import bpy

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
# set our level distances.
distances = [0, 3, 4, 5, 6] #XNN_LOD1 = 3
# objects in file with naming conv.
obs = [o for o in bpy.data.objects
        if len(o.name) == 3
        and o.name[0].isalpha() and o.name[0].isupper()
        and o.name[1:].isdigit()]

for o in obs:
    levobs = reversed([(i, bpy.data.objects.get("%s_LOD%d" % (o.name, i))) for i in range(5)])
    for i, ob in levobs:
        if not ob:
            continue
        ob.name = "%s_LOD%d" % (o.name, i + 1)
```

and change `name = "%s_LOD%d" % (o.name, lev_index - 1)` to `name = "%s_LOD%d" % (o.name, lev_index)` in first script above.

Comment: As stupid as I feel asking this: "NOT recommended since they will show as not set in UI" what does that mean?

Comment: @Haunt_House nevermind, stuffed up in testing, removed rather than unlinked from scene. (removed)

Answer (score 2):

This was supposed to be the non-Python solution:

Do a rightclick on the first of your objects.
Go to the menu Select >> Select Pattern...

Type in "X??". That'll select all objects starting with X being 3 characters long.

**Road one:**

Enter the desired number into the Distance field of your active object.
Right-click the button and choose 'Copy To Selected'

**Road two:**

Alt-leftclick the button and enter the number. All objects will have the same value.

**That was the plan until I actually tried it. Doesn't work. Blender thinks that stuff isn't copyable, so, Python it is.**

```
import bpy

prefix = 'X'
dist = 7.0 # distance you wish to copy
llevel = 1 # change for higher levels

c = 0 # just a counter to create a sense of accomplishment
for a in bpy.data.objects: # goes through all objects in your blendfile
    n = a.name # get the object's name
    if len(n) == 3 and n[0] == prefix: # If the names length is 3 and starts with x
        if len(a.lod_levels) > 0: # and if there actually are lod levels
            a.lod_levels[llevel].distance = dist # then assign the distance to them
            c += 1

print("I have successfully changed {} Objects".format(c)) # victory message
```

It's actually not too far away from your pseudocode, so I hope your survivability regarding python powers will increase.